# Show custom toast over the layout like AppMsg

Tags: android, toast

I want to show custom toast message on the top of the layout, LIKE e.g - when there is "No Internet connection." For that thing I am using [AppMsg library from here.](https://github.com/johnkil/Android-AppMsg)

But this library has few issues like it keeps showing message forever. I need the same type of implementation.

Anyone please suggest ?

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your Toastview like this,

```
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View toastLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.custom_toast_layout));
            Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
            toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setView(toastLayout);
            toast.show();
```

custom_toast  layout,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Custom Android Toast View Example" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/show_custom_toast"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:text="Show Custom Toast" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I need an implementation like AppMsg Class. I don't want to add a custom of my own. Sorry and thanks for answering